# I want to make Combobox name using Variable which will loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

```
int i=1;
int b=1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    b++;

    if (i < b) {

        ComboBox nama = new ComboBox();

       /* comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(39, locacom*angka);
        comboBox2.Name = "comboBox"+angka;
        comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 21);
        comboBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        comboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Controls.Add(comboBox2);
        label3.Text = i.ToString();
        i++;
        */
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "Something went wrong";
    }

    label4.Text = angka.ToString();
    label5.Text = i.ToString();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

I already tried some 
I can't came up with something new
i.e:

```
ComboBox name + i.toString() = new ComboBox();
var names = name + i.toString();
ComboBox names = new ComboBox();
```

Another question: What will happend if I can make combobox using the same name?

Comment: What you are trying to do is a very common mistake. The proper solution to the problem you have are arrays and other collections.

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?  It appears that you want that every time someone clicks a button, you create a new combo box and drop it on the form.  What's not working (well, other than the commented out code isn't running)?  You can set the name property to any string, I have no idea what "angka" is, but you could do something like: `ComboBox myCombo = new ComboBox();` and then `myCombo.Name = "Combo"+b.ToString();` and it _Should Just Work_ (well, the naming part).  By the way, it would be nice if you posted enough code for us to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Flydog57 i want to call  the combo  to multiply things, did can call the combo from myCombo.name?

Comment: You are going to need to be more explicit about what you are talking about.  Post more code and explain things together.  In general, you don't _call_ a combo box, you _initialize_ it and then _react_ to events (like someone selecting a value or typing into the text box part of it).  I really don't understand "I want to call the combo to multiply things".  Generally you work with combo boxes with references (for example, the `sender` parameter on events).  You can access any control by name by using `Find`

Comment: @Flydog57 all i want is to be able to make comboBox name using variable and to call i later ComboBox nama = new ComboBox();<<this nama i want to make like nama+i which i is int i want to combine two of them

Comment: OK, in a statement like `ComboBox nama = new ComboBox();`, the `nama` part is the name of a variable typed to contain a reference to a ComboBox instance. That name is compiled into your program and can't be changed at runtime (the way the `Name` property can be (as in your code: `comboBox2.Name = "comboBox"+angka;`).  If you want to keep a reference to your newly created combo box (other than via the Form's Controls collection), you will need to have a `List<ComboBox>` or other similar collection.  Why do you think you want what you are asking?  How would you use it?

Comment: i tough it would be easy if i'm not using List<ComboBox>, i want to use it to call another value in data table


(I'm never using List<COmboBox> before so , i dont really understand to fill the combo into list<comboBox>)